# How to create an array from variables in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash array from a list of variables, as you can see in that example:

```
PROJECT="testproject"
VERSION="3.1.0"
CONTRIBUTORS="Person, Other Person"

values[0]=$PROJECT
values[1]=$VERSION
values[2]=$CONTRIBUTORS

#values=($PROJECT, $VERSION, $CONTRIBUTORS)
echo $values

for v in "${values[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

But when I run that script (in a Mac Terminal), the only output is

```
testproject
```

But I expected that each value is printed twice (once in `echo $values`, once in the loop).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$v` and `$i` are not the same variable.

Comment: The commented out syntax should be `values=("$PROJECT" "$VERSION" "$CONTRIBUTORS")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... 
for v in "${values[@]}"
do
    echo $i  # supposed to be $v
done
```